# How to unit test Event Emitter in service

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a service called EmitterService like below.

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class EmitterService {
    public helpDisplayEmitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
```

I have injected that service into a component in the constructor. I have a method called getHelpDisplay() and there I am emitting the value to the emitter.

```
export class MainPageComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
constructor(public emitter: EmitterService) { }

 getHelpDisplay(helpItem: any) {
    this.helpValue = helpItem;
    this.emitter.helpDisplayEmitter.emit(this.helpValue);
  }
}
```

I want to write a unit test case for this particular emitter but I am getting error please help me with this.

spec file.

```
describe('MainpageComponent', () => {
  let component: MainPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainPageComponent>;
  let mainpage, element, de;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [MainPageComponent, EmitterService]
    });
  });

it('should emit false via createCustomer$ from breadCrumbService', inject([EmitterService], (service: EmitterService) => {    
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainPageComponent);
    mainpage = fixture.componentInstance;

    mainpage.getHelpDisplay("helpItem");
    expect(service.helpDisplayEmitter.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("helpItem");
  }));
```

I am getting the below error...

```
Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
        Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)
        Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
        Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...arguments)
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/mainpage/main-page.component.spec.ts:54:45)
            at TestBedRender3.execute (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:1953:1)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:2629:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push.QpwO.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:363:1)
            at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:123:1)
Chrome Headless 91.0.4472.124 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 584 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.559 secs)
Chrome Headless 91.0.4472.124 (Windows 10) MainpageComponent should emit false via createCustomer$ from breadCrumbService FAILED
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't spy on `service.helpDisplayEmitter.emit()` method. Use [spyOn](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOn) to install a spy onto an existing object.

E.g.

`main-page.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmitterService } from './emitter.service';

@Component({})
export class MainPageComponent {
  helpValue;
  constructor(public emitter: EmitterService) {}

  getHelpDisplay(helpItem: any) {
    this.helpValue = helpItem;
    this.emitter.helpDisplayEmitter.emit(this.helpValue);
  }
}
```

`emitter.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class EmitterService {
  public helpDisplayEmitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

`main-page.component.test.ts`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { EmitterService } from './emitter.service';
import { MainPageComponent } from './main-page.component';

fdescribe('MainpageComponent', () => {
  let component: MainPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainPageComponent>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MainPageComponent],
      providers: [EmitterService],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should emit false via createCustomer$ from breadCrumbService', inject(
    [EmitterService],
    (service: EmitterService) => {
      spyOn(service.helpDisplayEmitter, 'emit');
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainPageComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      component.getHelpDisplay('helpItem');
      expect(service.helpDisplayEmitter.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('helpItem');
    }
  ));
});
```

package versions:

```json
"@angular/core": "~11.0.3",
"@angular/cli": "~11.0.3",
```